# In Android, does my Google account saves my custom words from the dictionary of the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, google-account, dictionary, gboard

In Android, does my Google account saves my custom words from the dictionary of the keyboard?

Additionally, is there a way to import/export that custom dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Android doesn't saves your custom words from the dictionary of the keyboard in your Google account. Normally, the default keyboard doesn't automatically sync your personal (custom) dictionary. But you can email it or make a backup of it on an SD card.

- Setting -> Keyboard -> Personal Dictionary

OR

- Setting -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Type(eg HTC Sence Input) -> Personal Dictionary

Comment: Just a note: SwiftKey has a backup to cloud option that uses your Google account. VERY useful. It's free now on the Play Store too afaik.

Comment: I fail to see how this explains how to import or export at all.

Answer (score -2):

Google saves all custom words up to 5 years

Comment: Can you back that with a source?

Comment: This like saying "Trump pays taxes"; where's the proof of that statement?